# oracle sql pivot is grouping my data

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm having a problem creating a query using pivot.
I have a table that have 4 columns

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
1    | 1    |   5  | 2
1    | 2    |   6  | 2
1    | 3    |   7  | 2
1    | 4    |   8  | 2
1    | 1    |   5  | 2
1    | 2    |   6  | 2
1    | 3    |   7  | 2
1    | 4    |   8  | 2
```

I am using pivot so I can output items like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
```

Here is the query:

```
select col1, "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"
from (
   select col1, col2, col3
   from tbl
   where col4 = 2
)
pivot 
(
   max(col2)
   for col3
   in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
)
```

The code works all the time excepct when I have 2 identical records in the database. It groups then and display as one. I'd like to output it as 2 seperate but same rows. The easiest fix I see is that I include another column in the table that would work as ID. But because I won't be using this ID anywhere else I think it is kinda pointless and also it would be easier and less work to just change code a little bit.

The code above outputs this:

```
1 5 6 7 8 9
```

and I'd like this:

```
1 5 6 7 8 9
1 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: You're right; you're going to need an extra column to determine the subsets of the data. This might just be a row_number() that you use to group all the rows into "first row of the (col1, col2, col3) values, second row of the (col1, col2, col3) values, etc"

Comment: Please, choose one DBMS (Sql Server or Oracle) or your question is valid for either?

Comment: @Boneist Yes seems like this is the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add another column using the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT t.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4
                                    ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
         FROM   tbl t )
PIVOT  ( MAX( Col2 ) FOR Col3 IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 /* ..., 24*/ ) );
```

**Output**

```
COL1 COL4 RN 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
---- ---- -- - - - - - - - - - --
   1    2  1         1 2 3 4
   1    2  2         1 2 3 4
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I solved the problem by adding another column to the table that works as ID. and then my solution works. Thanks anyway